# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I solve this error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]. When I click submit at form to create event rails show me this error.

My routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'logout', to: 'user_sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :topics do
    member do
      put 'vote' => "topics#vote"
      get 'refresh_statistic' => "topics#refresh_statistic"
    end
  end

  resources :subtopics do
    member do
      put 'vote' => "subtopics#vote"
      get 'refresh_statistic' => "subtopics#refresh_statistic"
    end
  end

  root :to => "topics#show"

  resources :comments do
    member do
      put "like" => "comments#like"
    end
  end

  resources :events
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'update_password'
    end
  end
end
```

Form to add new event

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="selector">
    <%= f.label 'Owner type' %>
    <%= f.select :owner_type, options_for_select([['Topic','Topic'], ['Subtopic', 'Subtopic']])  %>
    <%= f.label 'Owner id' %>
    <% if params[:owner_type] == 'Topic' %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:owner_id, Topic.all, :id, :name, selected: (params[:owner_id ])) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:owner_id, Subtopic.all, :id, :name, selected: (params[:owner_id])) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit(@event) %>
<% end %>
```

Event controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: %i[show edit update create]

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(create_params)
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end

  def update
    if @event.update_attributes(update_params)
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  private

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Rails show error at create action, redirect_to event_path(@event) line. Help me if possible, I'm at a time with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `create` action needs to call `#save` on the new `@event` in a similar pattern to your `update` action.

It would be like:

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(create_params)
  if @event.save
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: @patrickmcgaw like that?
`def create
    event = Event.new(create_params)
    event.save
    redirect_to event_path(event)
  end`